# Solution transport equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have to solve the following equation
$$\partial_t v+2A\cdot\nabla v-iB(x)\cdot Av=0$$
where $A$ is a constant vector and $B$ a smooth vector field.
I can solve the transport equation $\partial_t v+2A\cdot\nabla v=0$ with characteristic method; how to treat the remaining term? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation, if expanded, reads:

$$ v_t + 2A_x v_x + 2A_y v_y + 2A_z v_z = i \, \mathbf{B}(x) \cdot \mathbf{A} \, v.  $$

This is a linear 1st order PDE for which the method of characteristics reads:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1} =  \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2A_x}  = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{2A_y}  = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2A_z} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{i \, \mathbf{B}(x) \cdot \mathbf{A}  }.  $$

Let me know if this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I've solved. Thanks for your hint.